# how to zip in rxjava

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, rx-java

Hi I'm a newbie with RXJava,I am trying to work on my first RxJava example that like below

```
Observable<String> myObservable = Observable.create(
            new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {
                public void call(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    subscriber.onNext("hello world");
                    subscriber.onCompleted();
                }
            }
    ).subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation());

    Observable<String> myObservable1 = Observable.just("thank you");

    Observable observable3 = Observable.zip(myObservable, myObservable1, new Func2<String,String,String>() {
        @Override
        public String call(String o, String o2) {
            return o+":"+o2;
        }
    });

    observable3.subscribe(new Action1<String>() {
        @Override
        public void call(String o) {
            System.out.println("before");
            System.out.println(o);
        }
    });
System.out.println("after");
```

I want to print `before` then `after`,how I to do that with rxjava and without `sleep`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way:

```
 Observable<String> myObservable = Observable.create(
            new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {
                public void call(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {
                    subscriber.onNext("hello world");
                    subscriber.onCompleted();
                }
            }
    ).subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation());

    Observable<String> myObservable1 = Observable.just("thank you");

    Observable observable3 = Observable.zip(myObservable, myObservable1, new Func2<String,String,String>() {
        @Override
        public String call(String o, String o2) {
            return o+":"+o2;
        }
    });

    Observable.just("before").concatWith(observable3).concatWith(Observable.just("after")).toBlocking().subscribe(new Action1<String>() {
        @Override
        public void call(String s) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    });
```

Result is:

before
hello world:thank you
after